# Parameter count not allowed in twitter filter stream?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I am using the following url to stream twitter data.

http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?count=-150&follow=16256661&track=indiana

Without the count the stream works perfectly fine.  With the count I get the following message.

```
Parameter count not allowed in role statusDefaultFiltered
```

The documentation here specifically says the count parameter is allowed.  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods

I am trying to use the count as a failsafe for when either our server goes down or perhaps the twitter server goes down to go back and retrieve previous tweets we may have missed.  Can someone explain to me if I am going about this the wrong way, weather the documentation is now wrong or what the error message is trying to tell me.  Google seems to not find much when searching for this error message.

**EDIT**

I am looking for a way to use count with the filter stream in any possible way I can.  I understand count is not allowed with track now.  I will check the answer of anyone who can provide either a valid request using the count parameter in the filter stream or can provide a decent explanation of Default access role and various other roles

I have changed my request to this:

http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?follow=16256661&count=-150

However this does not work and returns the same error even though I have taken out the track parameter.  I cannot get the count parameter to work within in context of the filter stream no matter what other parameters I pass to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filter method filters the stream based on the parameters given. The parameter can be follow,track or location.One can specify multiple followids/trackwords/loc.
By default you get minimum access which should be sufficient in most of the cases which is 400 track keywords, 5,000 follow userids and 25 0.1-360 degree location boxes. 
For people/organizations which need higher level of accesses twitter provides various access roles:

1. Shadow role - 100,000 follow userids
2. Birddog rolw - 400,000 follow userids
3. Restricted Track role - 10,000 track keywords
4. Partner Track role - 200,000 track keywords
5. locRestricted role - 200 0.1-360 degree location boxes 
   There are other roles like Firehose,Gardenhose which are not applicable to this method.

To provide your twitter account with any of the above roles, one has to request twitter team (mail to api@twitter.com) to grant an increased role explaining why it is used.
They decide whether you are eligible for that role and reply something like

```
Got it!

Your request made it to Twitter Support. Someone from our support team will review it as soon as possible.

You can review the status of your request and add additional comments by visiting support.twitter.com & clicking on "Check Existing Tickets" (in the top-right corner of the page).
```

If they think your app deserves a higher access level, they'll grant it, else they will suggest you to go with lesser access role suitable for your application.

Count parameter is allowed only with Firehose, Links, Birddog and Shadow roles. So you can request one of Birddog or shadow roles depending on how many users you want to follow and file a request. If it gets approved, you can get the backlog statuses with this parameter in case you miss them.
If you do not need to follow so many users but need to make sure you do not miss any statuses of the users you follow, you can run multiple instances (2-3) with different user accounts following the same userids (hope that it is not abusing twitter policies) and write it to some database eliminating duplicates, so there is a very less chances of all instances being down at the same time.
Hope this helps, sorry for the previous reply.

Comment: I'm off to ask the twitter fairies for higher level access, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Twitter no longer grants these access levels, is that correct?